# github actions- if condition inside the for loop

Tags: github-actions

I'm tring to run the below workflow using for loop with if condition inside, but the action is parsed with an error, what is my mistake?

workflow:

```html
on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

   

jobs:

  analysis:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Setup Cpp Check
      run: sudo apt-get install cppcheck
    - name: Run Static Analysis
      run: cppcheck . --force --error-exitcode=1
  unit_test:
  #  needs: Scan_changes
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Setup Ruby
      run: sudo apt-get install ruby
    - name: Setup Ceedling
      run: sudo gem install ceedling
    - name: Get changed files
      id: changed-files
      uses: tj-actions/changed-files@v34
      with:
        dir_names: true
        files: |
          code/**
    - name: Unit Test for Changed modules
      run: |
        for file in ${{ steps.changed-files.outputs.all_changed_files }}; do
          if: contains('$file', 'SomeString')
          echo "$file was changed"
        done
    - name: Test
      run: |
        ceedling
```

and the output is
[image]

So i'm not sure what is the propore syntex for the if condition inside the fore loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is not valid `bash` script code. You should do something like:

```
    - name: Unit Test for Changed modules
      run: |
        for file in ${{ steps.changed-files.outputs.all_changed_files }}; do
          if [[ $file =~ "SomeString" ]]; then
            echo "$file was changed"
          fi
        done
```